# Android : display html data

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I want to display the content of an html page and an image to the right of that in my view.

So i have defined my layout as

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrllvwNo1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/home_bg">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/aboutcmkimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:src="@drawable/about"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <WebView android:id="@+id/aboutcmk" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aboutcmkimage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and

I try to load the html page as below

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.aboutcmk);
         web.loadData(getString(R.layout.about),"texl/html","utf-8");
```

in this case i am getting the error
"this page contains error at line1 ... "

if I try

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,getString(R.layout.about),"texl/html","utf-8",null);
```

no html output and no error

In both case the image is coming

Can anyone help me in debugging

My html has bullets , so i cannot use textview instead of webview

here is the definition of  my htmlstring in xml file

```
<string name="About"><html><body><b>What is CMK?</b> ......</body></html>
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I see you have `<string name="About">` in your HTML specification. Could you clarify what it is? As far as I know HTML doesn't have any such tag.

Comment: its my definition in the xml file . i have kept the html string in the string variable About

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you put this line **What is CMK?** ......  in strings.xml if yes then the correction is in this line
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,getString(R.layout.about),"texl/html","utf-8",null);

```
Correct one:

web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getString(R.string.About), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: that was a big blunder . thanks a lot.                                                    With this i am getting the html displayed but                                       1. the tags are not properly decoded ( no bold, no bullets etc displayed  . any pointers on this would be great help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have saved your HTML specification as a string resource, your should access it as `R.string.about` and not `R.layout.about`. Change that, if it still doesn't work, try escaping the less than characters in your string, like this :

```
<string name="about">&lt;html>&lt;body>&lt;b>What is CMK?&lt;/b> ......&lt;/body>&lt;/html> </string>
```

I think you will have to escape the less than characters. Before loading the text, Log it. You'll see the problem.

Comment: yes the < had to be escaped. Thanks a lot                                                 Unfortunately i can mark only one answer as correct.. This one is also absolutely right. Thanks again

Comment: No, problem. If you liked my answer just upvote it. Btw, you can change your choice of the right answer if you want to (not that you have to).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the HTML in `strings.xml`, you can store it in its own file in the `res/raw/` directory. For example, let's say you save the file in `res/raw/mypage.html`. I haven't tested this, but you should be able to open up raw resources and load them up in a `WebView` like:

```
try {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.mypage);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(bytes);

    String htmlStr = new String(bytes);
    webView.loadData(htmlStr, "text/html", "UTF-8");
} catch(Exception e) {
    //blah
}
```